# subracting minutes and seconds in php datetime

Tags: php

I have this datetime code below. I want to subtract 23 hours and 59 minutes in $begin variable:

```
 $date = 2016-03-14 23:59:59;
 $given = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo"));
 $given->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
 $end = $given->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
 $begin = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('-23 hours',strtotime($end)));
```

Now The output is:

```
$end is: 2016-03-14 14:59:59
$begin is: 2016-03-13 15:59:59
```

The output I want is:

```
 $end is: 2016-03-14 14:59:59
 $begin is: 2016-03-13 15:00:00
```

How can I subtract the minutes in seconds in begin? Or there is a best way to do it?

Comment: As you just want to change the hour, try this: `echo $begin = date('Y-m-d H:00:00',strtotime('-23 hours', strtotime($end)));`

Comment: Consider using http://carbon.nesbot.com/, which extends DateTime with a bunch of useful features. You'd do `$date->subHours(23)->subMinutes(59)` in its API.

Comment: @FrayneKonok you should post as a answer !!

Comment: Some silly answers gives me some downvote, I already experienced of it. So i don't do that before OP want. But thanks for your comment. @DavidJawphan

Comment: @FrayneKonok post your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Mary, I make it for only you.

Comment: Just for clarity, you don't want to "subract" anything but rather round to full hours, right? If yes, do you want to round down, up or normally? While you're at it, consider removing the offset of 23 hours, because it only makes your question even less understandable. The point is that subtracting an offset is something for which DateTime offers an interfaces, which should be trivial to locate with minimal research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you just want to change the hour, you can make this to get the desire result, but you also can do something else like **Amit Roy** did or **ceejayoz** suggest. This is a pretty simple solution, just do it: reset the min and sec to 00 so that your output shows like you want.

```
echo $begin = date('Y-m-d H:00:00',strtotime('-23 hours', strtotime($end)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **DateInterval** class with the **DateTime::sub** method.

Example:

```
$begin_datetime = $given->sub(new DateInterval('PT23H59M00S'));
$begin = $begin_datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php
http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php

Answer (score 0):

**[As Frayne make the comment.]** As you just want to change the hour, not the min or sec, you have to set the min and sec to 00:00 as your desire output.

```
echo $begin = date('Y-m-d H:00:00',strtotime('-23 hours', strtotime($end)));
```

You can did this thing in many different ways, and this is one way.

Comment: OMG!! You just make my answer as your. Okey no problem. Carry on.

Comment: Mixing `DateTime` with legacy `date()` functions seems pointless and retrograde. `DateTime` is a powerful class that can do everything you need and there's absolutely no reason to resource to `date()`, `strtotime()` or any of that.

Comment: @Havenard, I make it from the comment of Frayne. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I did this because of the OP's script. Yes @Havenard you are sure about the DateTime.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do this to get desired result. You were subtracting hours alone

```
$begin = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('-23 hours',strtotime($end)));
```

You have to subtract min and sec too

```
$begin = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('-23 hours -59 minutes -59 seconds',strtotime($end)));
```

Finally you get this code:

```
$date = "2016-03-14 23:59:59";
$given = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo"));
$given->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$end = $given->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
echo $begin = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('-23 hours -59 minutes -59 seconds',strtotime($end))); //2016-03-13 15:00:00
```

Comment: I don't DV you, But want to give you a suggestion, If you make an answer than must add some meaningful description so later user can understand what you do without debugging you script.

Comment: @Frayne Konok was that so complex to understand. Wasnt that self explanatory. Where it is required I give explanations. For this you negatively voted.

Comment: As i already told you **I don't DV(downvote) you**, You have to add what you change here to meet the OP's requirement.

Comment: @Frayne Konok sorry I didnt knew what DV means.